# How to install reviewboard with nginx?

Tags: nginx

Does anyone how to install reviewboard with nginx? It currently only has docs for apache and lighty.

Thanks

Comment: It's important to understand the server software you're using.  When you have an idea of how to construct virtualhosts in Nginx, the answer to this question will become clear.

Read the documentation for Nginx, and reviewboard, and read the Apache and Lighttpd instructions.  Then experiment, and see if you can get it right.

Answer (score 1):

http://rramsden.ca/blog/2011/09/26/nginx-reviewboard/

I had issue with that setup, replaced "root" with "alias" and works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This module is not compiled by default and must be specified using the
--with-http_stub_status_module

You can check your binary (packaged or not) with

```
nginx -V
```

I would suggest doing something like this in your server config

```
 location /server-status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
      allow 10.0.0.0/24;
      deny all;
    }
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

ReviewBoard is a Django based application that can be used through WSGI. With nginx this usually means running ReviewBoard with an WSGI server (for example see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-web-servers-for-python-based-web-applications) for a list), and proxying it with nginx.

You can find generic instructions about running a Django application behind nginx in the [official documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/gateway-uwsgi-django/)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/huyphan/9609bd1ead8b5c64a6ae), I found a gist with example configurations for running ReviewBoard with uwsgi e nginx.